# Как правильно сделать "push"?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch, git-push

Подскажите как выбрать ветку в которую хочу сделать пуш...

Вот у меня есть локальная ветка `featureRefactorCameraHelper` и есть локальная ветка `develop` , я закончил с веткой `featureRefactorCameraHelper` и теперь хочу ее запушить в локальную ветку `develop` я делаю коммит и за ним делаю пуш и получаю вот такое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) как выбрать ветку в которую я хочу сделать пуш
2) что означает эта строчка

```
featureRefactorCameraHelper -> origin:+featureRefactorCameraHelper
```

а под ней `test` ... Куда пойдет этот пуш?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и теперь хочу ее запушить в локальную ветку develop

нельзя запушить одну локальную ветку в другую. Запушить можно только на удаленный сервер. А Вы скорее всего хотите слить изменения двух веток вместе. Это называется мержд (merge).  Как это делать в idea - я не зняю, я делаю это (и настойчиво рекомендую делать это) в консоли. А там все просто

```
git checkout develop # перешли в develop
git merge featureRefactorCameraHelper # слили
```

> `featureRefactorCameraHelper -> origin:+featureRefactorCameraHelper`

таким не хитрым образом среда показывает, что Ваша ветка `featureRefactorCameraHelper` будет отправлена на сервер с псевдонимом `origin` (это имя по умолчанию для удаленного сервера). А плюсик видимо значит, что эту ветку там создадут, если ее там нет.

Comment: Можно еще раз) Значит у меня на сервере есть ветка `master` (для релизов) и рядом там же я создаю ветку `dev`. Когда мне нужно внести изменения, то я создаю локальную ветку `feature` (кстати вопрос по пути, когда я создаю локальную ветку `feature` то она уже содержит последние изменения или нужно делать pull), работаю с ней и когда закончил, то делаю пуш в ветку `dev` на сервере.  А когда готов релиз то делаю пуш из ветки `dev` в ветку `master`, верно?

Comment: не нужно на сервере "создавать ветку". `когда я создаю локальную ветку feature то она уже содержит последние изменения ` - она содержит ровно то, что было в ветке, от которой ее ответвили. Делать pull нет смысла - на сервере то ее нет.
Делать пуш с ветки feature в dev на сервере можно, но не нужно. ветка дев  - это для текущего рабочего кода, feature - для какой то новой штуки. master - это то, что в проде (но на самом деле Вы вольны выбирать свои названия для веток).

Comment: А вот насчет псевдонима ветки... Зачем он присваивается? Я сделал с локальной машины пуш на сервер и все... как используется этот псевдоним?

Comment: что такое "псевдоним ветки"? origin - это псевдоним сервера. И используется только для того, что бы не писат длинных имен.

Comment: Я вот только что сделал пуш и создалась удаленная ветка с таким же именем, теперь у меня 2 удаленные ветки, но как мне теперь смержить эти 2 удаленные ветки? `master` и `featureRefactorCameraHelper` ?

Comment: ага вроде получилось)) Спасибо!0)

Comment: мержить на сервере теоретически можно, но это следует делать только когда других вариантов больше нет и Вы очень хорошо понимаете, что Вы делаете.

Как поступить Вам - смержить эти ветки локально и потом запушить.